# Create POST Request with Postman

Tags: post, http-post, postman, restful-architecture, restful-authentication

This curl is working fine and returns the token as expected:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{ "username": "pere.peris@gmail.com","password": "password" }' "http://75.90.255.68:1133/canPeris/auth"
```

But when I do the same call using Postman app I get a **401 Unauthorized** as a return value

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the missing JSON inside the Body . click Raw combo box and add

```
{ "username": "pere.peris@gmail.com","password": "password" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function in Postman to generate curl:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets

On the right side under "Send" and "Save" just hit the Code Button/Link. Then select in the next window in the drop down cURL. So you see what cURL would be generated and compare it with the command line.

The `-d` option is described here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d